# print string between multiple brackets and multiple lines on a single line

Tags: linux, text-processing, awk

I have following output file and need to print string between braces on multiple lines on a single line.

input :

```
CLUSQMGR(server1)                      CHANNEL(channel name)
CONNAME(server1.opr.test.company.com(1414))

CLUSQMGR(server2)                      CHANNEL(channel name)
CONNAME(server2.opr.test.company.com(1414))
```

Ouput needed: I will need the string in first brackets after CLUSQMGR and string in first brackets after CONNAME in a single line seperated by a space like below.

```
server1 server1.opr.test.company.com(1414)
server2 server2.opr.test.company.com(1414)
```

I tried :

```
awk -F'[()]' '{print $2 $3}'
```

but get this :

```
server1                    CHANNEL
server1.opr.test.company.com1414
server2                    CHANNEL
server2.opr.test.company.com1414
```

Comment: You can try `awk -F'[()]' '{n=$2; getline; print n " "$2"("$3")"}' yourfile`  if the output doesn't change.

Comment: `echo 'server1 server1.opr.test.company.com(1414)'` would do it. Please try and specify the requirements more clearly. Do you need what's in the matched pairs of parenthesis that follow either  `CLUSQMGR` or `CONNAME`. Or the first blank separated field of each line stripped of everything up to the first `(` and the trailing `)`? ...?

Comment: @val0x00ff - This kind of worked, but it had to parenthesis added to top and bottom of the output like below 
                                                               
`()
()
server1 server1.opr.test.company.com(1414)
server2 server2.opr.test.company.com(1414)
()
()`

Answer (score 1):

If `sed` is okay for you:

```
sed '/CLUSQMGR(/!d;s///;N;s/).*\n[^(]*(/ /;s/)$//'
```

Explanation:

- Main idea: both lines come in as a pair, so if the first of the pair is found, read the next and do some replacing to remove everything not needed
- `/CLUSQMGR(/!d` ignores all lines not containing `CLUSQMGR(`, just in case there can be other lines you don't want
- `s///`removes the last pattern, which is the `CLUSQMGR(`
- `N` appends the next line to the pattern space, with an embedded  newline
- `s/).*\n[^(]*(/ /` replaces everything from the closing bracket to the first opening bracket of the second line with a whitespace. This is done by anchoring the pattern at the newline (`\n`) and `[^(]*` matching any number of characters except for the `(`
- `s/)$//` removes the trailing `)`

Comment: working perfectly. yes please. can you explain

Answer (score 0):

**`Awk`** solution:

```
awk 'function get_srv_data(sep) {    # get/extract server data
         gsub(/^[^(]+\(|\)$/, "", $1);
         printf $1 sep;
     }
     /^CLUSQMGR/{ get_srv_data(OFS) }
     /^CONNAME/ { get_srv_data(ORS) }' file
```

The output:

```
server1 server1.opr.test.company.com(1414)
server2 server2.opr.test.company.com(1414)
```